# Repairing clay foundation drain

Tags: french-drain

I broke a clay foundation drain under my basement slab while jackhammering through the slab. To be clear, this clay pipe is for draining groundwater, it's not a sewer pipe and it is under my basement floor near the centre of the room. Should I replace this roughly 4' section of clay foundation drain with solid or perforated PVC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: French drain pipe

Comment: do you plan to put concrete over it ?

Comment: this would be good time to install a Y junction to be able to clean the mud

Comment: Definitely not perforated. The question is if you can use PVC below grade or if it needs to be clay or iron.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes I plan on putting concrete over it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you mean by ground water, if the pipe is guiding water from elsewhere, it implies a solid pipe, therefore the water flows through it.

If on the other hand the pipe is accepting water from its surrounding and then guides it through, then it needs perforated at it's top half diameter but solid the bottom half, depending on the size of the pipe and the amount of water that it has to guide.

A sewege pipe on the other hand is performated all the way around, it's job is to let water seep out of it and of course to keep dirt at bay.

This is not the type of pipe you want there.  It has little meaning.

Comment: Wait... you're saying that a _sewage_ pipe is _perforated_? Wouldn't that let raw sewage leak out all over the place, contaminating the ground water? Don't you mean that a surface water drain pipe would be perforated to allow water to enter, giving the water a generally easier path to flow and direct the water away from the foundation? Correct that (or defend the position) and I'll give you an up vote.

Comment: @FreeMan, The sewage pipe in this context refers to drain field.  Yes that is the whole point of it.  It is to let the sewage spread everywhere and dry out indeed.  You can read all about it on the internet. What is the role of drain field in septic sewage system.   Your well is to be kept 100 feet away from any septic system, but of course.

Comment: There is rather a _significant_ difference between a septic system leach field (what you're describing, and with which I'm reasonably familiar), and the "foundation drain ... To be clear, this clay pipe is for draining groundwater, it's not a sewer pipe" the OP specifically states in his question.

Comment: @FreeMan,  I know.   You asked about septic sewage pipe and I responded to you.  In regard to the post I expolained much more, covered more situations. It is obvious. Two types of so called foundation/fresh water drain....is it gathering and guiding or it just guiding?